# Is there a difference between craftable squad surplus vouchers and uncraftable ones?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

Can someone explain to me the difference between these 2 Squad Surplus Vouchers for Mann vs Machine Mode on TF2?

[image: Uncraftable Vouchers] and [image: Regular Vouchers]

1. Do these 2 vouchers work differently?
2. How is it possible to even acquire an uncraftable version? From what I understand everything from the tf2 store is craftable now,
3. According to the current value the uncraftable version is 4 ref and craftable version is 5 ref? Is this because the 2 work different? I Don't understand this.

Comment: Well technically they're not craftable either way and never have been. Can you link to the ones you show in the images?

Comment: just search for vouchers in outpost, you'll see them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference between the two. I believe buying something from the Mann Co. Store makes said item uncraftable for a week, but that might have changed in my absence from TF2. And as for the price difference, I'm fairly certain it follows the general trend that uncraftables are cheaper than regular items.

Comment: You're right, there is no difference in functionality. All 'tool' items (Decals, Name Tags, Descriptions, Keys etc) are uncraftable whether or not they have 'uncraftable' on them, it's likely that this field was only added to the items later, and older items made before this point did not show it.